# Excel download in a zip file

Tags: java, spring

The followling api can be call to download as .xlsx.

I would like to download the excel file inside the .zip file

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/excelDownload", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<Resource> excelDownload() throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = null;
    ResponseEntity<Resource> excelFile = null;
    try {
        HashMap<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
        param = (HashMap<String, String>) session.getAttribute("mySession");

        List<BranchInfoDTO> BranchInfoDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BranchInfoDTOList = shopInfoService.selectMyListExcelDownload(param);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<List<String>> dataList = getDownloadData(BranchInfoDTOList);
        // the dataList part has no problem at the moment

        String folderName = getSessionUser().getName() + DateUtil.date2String(new Date(), DateUtil.YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS);
        String baseDirPath = tempDirPath + File.separator + folderName;
        InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(ExcelHelper.downloadToExcel2(dataList)); // ExcelHelper.java will be seen below 

        excelFile = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + folderName + ".xlsx")
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
                .body(file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
        throw e;
    }
    return excelFile;
}
```

The following static function is in ExcelHelper.java

```
public static ByteArrayInputStream downloadToExcel2(List<List<String>> dataList) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        InputStream resourceAsStream = new FileInputStream(PROXY_FORMAT_LOCAL);
        Workbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(resourceAsStream);
        Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Data
        int rowIdx = 1;
        for (List<String> stringList : dataList) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);
            System.out.println("row = " + row);

            for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
                row.createCell(i).setCellValue(stringList.get(i));
            }
        }
        workBook.write(out);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("fail to import data to Excel file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

There is entity declare as ResponseEntity<byte[]> .
I would like to return as ResponseEntity<byte[]> which is for zip file.

E.g.

```
ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = ExcelFileInsideZip(excelFile);
return entity;
```

Or there may be other way to learn something
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a ZipOutputStream, e.g.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = ExcelHelper.downloadToExcel2(...);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("excel-file-name");
zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int length;
while((length = bis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
  zipOut.write(bytes, 0, length);
}
zipOut.close();
return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
```

and adjust response content type

```
.contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel"))
```

to

```
.contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress

Comment: Thank for your answer. Unfortunatly this is not work for me. However I learnt alot form the link.